# "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" error with process substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

In a fresh, clean bash instance I get as expected the following:

```
$ printf "a\td\n" | cat -vE
a   d$
$
$ file <(printf "a\td\n" | cat -vE)
/dev/fd/63: symbolic link to pipe:[6664004]
```

However I currently have a bash instance that returns:

```
$ printf "a\td\n" | cat -vE
a   d$
$
$ file <(printf "a\td\n" | cat -vE)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$
$ type -a printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
printf is /bin/printf
$
$ type -a file
file is /usr/bin/file
file is /bin/file
```

What could be causing this error?

If I compare the environment variables, there is no significant difference with a fresh bash instance. Similarly, I see nothing special in the variables that currently exist in the session. Any clue?...

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have the variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` set as I had earlier run `set -o posix`.

It was in my list of variables as `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` but it did not occur to me at first sight that this could be the cause. (I was rather searching for any interference with the names of the commands.)

Resetting using `set +o posix` solved the problem.

Comment: [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668265/170373) mentioned a while back that Bash 5.1 allows process substitutions even in POSIX mode.

Comment: Note that running `sh -a` on systems where `sh` is bash is enough to set that `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable (and all commands run within that sh session will be in POSIX mode).

Comment: On my system (Linux Mint 20.2): `bash --version` > `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`